# how to add image path for dynamically in pentaho report designer tool?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

We are using pentaho report designer tool, in this we want to create dynamic image path url for image-field, so please let me know how can we create formula for image path in pentaho report designer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a parameter using pentaho data integration , pass the value and call the report and assign the path wherever you required.